# I want to add/remove a label from all pods running in a given namespace

Tags: kubernetes

Using the below command labels can be added to a pod.

```
kubectl label pod <pod-name> {key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3}
```

What is the best way to add or remove a label, say, [ env: dev ] from all pods running in a given namespace.

Comment: Pods are immutable. Not sure this is a good idea. You need to modify the controlling Deployment, StatefulSet, DaemonSet, etc.

Comment: yes as mentioned, the best place should be the deployment, if the pod restarted they label will be set again from the deployment/daemonset controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...to add or remove a label, say, [ env: dev ] from all pods running
> in a given namespace.

Try:

`kubectl label pods --namespace <name> --all env=dev`  # <-- add

`kubectl label pods --namespace <name> --all env-`  # <-- remove